# FTP doesn't allow /usr/sbin/nologin user

Tags: linux, ftp, users, vsftpd

I want to setup a ftp for couple of ftp-only users with `vsftpd`. I configured the FTP to enable local user access. It works fine. But once I edit the users' shell to `/usr/sbin/nologin`, it couldn't log into the FTP with the following error:

```
Response:   220 Welcome to the Scent Library's File Service.
Command:    USER marketftp
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   530 Login incorrect.
```

Here is what I have done:

- All ftp-only user will have `/srv/ftp` as their home directory.The directory information is

  `/srv/ftp: drwxr-xr-x  3 root slftp 4.0K 2012-02-09 17:20 ftp/`
- All the ftp-only users will be in the group `slftp`;

  I created the user with `adduser` and ended up with this `/etc/passwd` entry: `marketftp:x:1001:1001::/srv/ftp:/usr/sbin/nologin`

  And this in `/etc/group`: `slftp:x:1001:marketftp`
- The `vsftpd` is configured with the following to limit the user to their own home except local users in the `vsftpd.chroot_list`:

  ```
  chroot_local_user=YES
  chroot_list_enable=YES
  chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
  ```

Where is my problem? As the FTP could be logged in by normal local users, the connection is fine. But why couldn't the ftp-only user login?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/FAQ.txt)

***Q) Help! Local users cannot log in.***

```
A) There are various possible problems.

A1) By default, vsftpd disables any logins other than anonymous logins. Put
local_enable=YES in your /etc/vsftpd.conf to allow local users to log in.

A2) vsftpd tries to link with PAM. (Run "ldd vsftpd" and look for libpam to
find out whether this has happened or not). If vsftpd links with PAM, then
you will need to have a PAM file installed for the vsftpd service. There is
a sample one for RedHat systems included in the "RedHat" directory - put it
under /etc/pam.d

A3) If vsftpd didn't link with PAM, then there are various possible issues. Is
the user's shell in /etc/shells? If you have shadowed passwords, does your
system have a "shadow.h" file in the include path?

**A4) If you are not using PAM, then vsftpd will do its own check for a valid
user shell in /etc/shells. You may need to disable this if you use an invalid
shell to disable logins other than FTP logins. Put check_shell=NO in your
/etc/vsftpd.conf.**
```

You are Case A4

Comment: Exactly. Add `/usr/sbin/nologin` in the `/etc/shells/` solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @steveyang,  there are users on the other answer saying that your suggestion has security issues.

Answer (score 7):

Look at `check_shell` in man vsftpd.conf:

```
Note! This option only has an effect for non-PAM builds of vsftpd.
If disabled, vsftpd will not check /etc/shells for a valid user
shell for local logins.

Default: YES
```

You can add `/usr/sbin/nologin` to `/etc/shells`. Simple and easy solution.

Another one is to change `vsftpd.conf/PAM` configuration.

Comment out this "auth ..." line in PAM case:

```
$ grep shells /etc/pam.d/vsftpd
auth    required        pam_shells.so
```

Answer (score 0):

They have no WRITE access to their own home-folder.

(Its **RWX R-X R-X** , owner **root**, group **slftp**)

This is usually enough cause to prevent FTP from work.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 with CentOS 7 there is a sulution to simply comment out pam_shell in /etc/pam.d/vsftpd. It just checks that /sbin/nologin not exist and denies.

Info from MANual:
*pam_shells is a PAM module that only allows access to the system if the users shell is listed in /etc/shells.*
..and /sbin/nologin is not.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score -3):

I put `/usr/sbin/nologin` in `/etc/shells` and vsftpd works fine.

Comment: Congratulations! You just opened a security hole big enough to drive not only a truck, but an entire transatlantic RORO ship filled with trucks, through.

Comment: This workaround needs to be removed as suggestion. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155139/does-usr-sbin-nologin-as-a-login-shell-serve-a-security-purpose