# vsftpd: user with /sbin/nologin fails even though in /etc/shells

Tags: centos, sftp, vsftpd

I'm running a simple vsftpd server.  The centos 7 box it runs on is connected to LDAP.  I need an SFTP user with no shell access, so I've set their shell in /etc/passwd to /sbin/nologin, and added /sbin/nologin to /etc/shells, and added check_shell=NO to my /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf file, but I cannot log in with SFTP. Changing the user's shell to /bin/bash causes the SFTP login to work fine.

I've looked at several answers but they all suggest the steps I've already taken (like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/358324/ftp-doesnt-allow-usr-sbin-nologin-user) one).  I'm on vsftpd version 3.0.2, and I have SELinux set to Permissive.

Comment: `vsftpd` is an _FTP_ server, not an _SFTP_ server.  Do you mean _FTPS_ instead?

Comment: Ah!  @Castaglia I'm smart, geez, thanks, that could be my issue.  I was confused because SFTP works fine when I set the user's shell to /bin/bash, but perhaps sshd is providing SFTP for me so that's why I'm confused.

Comment: SFTP uses ssh protocol, and FTP is cleartext authentication.